# Adding Language Support using .pot and .mo files to a WordPress Theme?

Tags: themes, theme-development

How do we add language support using .pot and .mo files in a WordPress theme? And how we retrieve the theme?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .po (Portable Object) file is like a small library containing all the English terms in the  theme with an empty column for non-English translations. Using software like Poedit, the .po file can be opened, translations can be added, and it can be saved, which also generates the .mo (Machine Object) file.

**With a suitably localized theme, the steps involved in translating it are:**

1. Run a tool over the code to produce
   a POT file (Portable Object
   Template), simply a list of all
   localizable text.
2. Use a plain text
       editor or a special localization
       tool to generate a translation for
       each piece of text. This produces a
       PO file (Portable Object). The only
       difference between a POT and PO file
       is that the PO file contains
       translations
3. Compile the PO file to
       produce a MO file (Machine Object),
       which can then be used in the theme
       or plugin.

**Open Source Software Needed for the translation process:**

[Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) a cross-platform gettext catalogs (.po files) editor

[Gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)  the GNU `gettext' utilities are a set of tools that provides a framework to help other GNU packages produce multi-lingual messages.

---

A complete guide and tutorial on translating WordPress themes can be found on [Urban Giraffe](http://urbangiraffe.com/articles/translating-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)

Comment: Nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

My first recommendation would be to read [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) in the WordPress Codex.

To add language support, the *first* thing you need to do is make sure all of your echoed content is passed through a filter that can handle internationalization (i.e `_e()` and `__()`).  Then you'll need to make sure everything is mapping to the same [text domain](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains).

From there, you'll use an external tool to parse all of your content for translatable strings, translate them, and save the appropriate language files.  Full instructions and a list of resources are available on the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) article I linked to above.